# Atof is not working in C and without atof is also not working in debug

Tags: c, debugging, atoi, atof, coocox

I have problems with Atof function. I am trying to convert string to float but it is not giving any error when I try in Coocox software in Debug section, Output is not showing anything. I tried two functions Atoi and Atof. When I use Atoi there is no output.When I use Atof The program starting restart. I put stdlib.h definition for atof in here.But it is atoff for float value in here.I tried same code in Dev C++ in C it is working very well. Other things I use without working Atof but this time again the program is restarting. This is working on Dev C. But not in Coocox. How can I solve the problem? There is only difference atoff! What can it be related? I used stdlib.h and there is no error in compilation!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    float c;
    int b;

    char *array[1] = {"52.43525"};

    b=(atoi(array[0])/100);
    c=((atof(array[0]))/100.0)*100.0;
    c/=60;
    c+=b;

    printf ("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}

-----stdlib.h----
double  _EXFUN(atof,(const char *__nptr));
#if __MISC_VISIBLE
float   _EXFUN(atoff,(const char *__nptr));
#endif
int _EXFUN(atoi,(const char *__nptr));
int _EXFUN(_atoi_r,(struct _reent *, const char *__nptr));
long    _EXFUN(atol,(const char *__nptr));
long    _EXFUN(_atol_r,(struct _reent *, const char *__nptr));
------------------------------------
```

Comment: If it is truly `atof()` that is not working, you should simplify the code to be sure the problem is specifically that.

Comment: When I remove atof() everything is working very well. There is no problem!

Comment: Curious, same problem if `float c` changed to `double c`?

Comment: Note that `(atoi(array[0]) / 100)` evaluates to 0.

Comment: I tried atof (double format) again same!

Comment: Some compilers see all this code and convert it to `puts("0.873921");`, negating any need for FP libraries.  Suggest making the code not so deterministic (e.g. add user input) and check that the compilation is including  FP support.

Comment: That is not what I meant by "simplify".  If you just atof a string literal and output it without the arithmetic expressions in order to exclude them.

Comment: @Nobody Your code, as posted, works perfectly for me, and I don't see anything wrong with it (besides a whole school of red herrings).  Suggest you try `"char *s = "52.43525"; c = atof(s)";`, or even `c = atof("52.43525");`, to try to narrow your problem down.

Comment: @chux : the simplest way to force the compiler not to optimise away the expressions is to declare the variables volatile.

Comment: @Clifford Good idea.

Comment: Iam using Cortex M3 and i added -mfloat-abi=softfb;-mfloat-abi=hard; Other thing,I read comment about hardware "There isn't any floating-point hardware in Cortex-M3, but support for C float and double are provided in software by most compilers/libraries." Can hardware effect?

Comment: hard to believe optimalisation with function changing. What compiler make such optuimalisation?

Comment: "char *s = "52.43525"; c = atof(s)";, or even c = atof("52.43525"); They were not working because I tried before.

Comment: Try `char s[] = "52.43525";`. All other forms result in a read-only literal and the library could choke on that.

Comment: @ Paul Ogilvie char s[] = "52.43525" I has just tried which is restarting again in Debug mode!

Comment: #define  RCC_CSR_SFTRSTF                    ((uint32_t)0x10000000)        /*!< Software Reset flag */ --_RCC_CSR-- When I look reset reason ,these are

Answer (score 1):

after correcting all the compiler warnings, this was the resulting code:

Note: since the array feature was not used, I changed it to a simple pointer.  This made no difference int the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
//#include <string.h> -- contents not used
#include <stdlib.h>  // atoi(), atof()

int main ()
{
    float c;
    int b;

    char *array = {"52.43525"};

    b =  atoi(array);
    c =  ( (float)( atof(array) ) / 100.0f ) * 100.0f;
    c /= 60.0f;
    c += (float)b;

    printf ("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

running the program resulted in:

```
52.873920
```

So if your compiler is not finding `atof()` it is a problem with the compiler.

Comment: it is restarting again.If the problem is compiler, What can I do?Which compiler link should I add?